Is there a Flutter equivalent of the pipes in Angular?
I am learning Angular, and I have discovered pipes, which not only seem very useful but should also be much more RAM-efficient than functions for data transformation. Is there an equivalent of Angular pipes in Flutter? Or is there something more efficient than functions when I have to do data transformation?

In Flutter I have not seen a concept exactly similar to Angular's Pipe. I think we will not have this kind of concept because Flutter is based on the Declarative UI philosophy without separation of the definition of views with different languages ​​such as HTML/Typescript/CSS.
An Angular pipe is just an invocation of a typescript function from the HTML template. This concept exists because we have this HTML/Typescript separation.
If your needs are to transform a string or a number, you can use the Dart extension concept. See https://dart.dev/language/extension-methods, this may eventually help you.
